# 2.8 import scale bug?

Tags: import, scale, units

I'm working in FormZ using Feet and exporting as such.

In Blender 2.79, I have no issue changing units to Imperial/Feet... the objects import properly, e.g. a 20' cube exported from FormZ (.obj) imports as a 20' cube.

However, in 2.8, the same settings result in an object that is anywhere from 3.28 to 3.94 times too large, e.g. a 20 cube exported from FormZ imports as a 65.6' cube. (1 mm = .0394 in.)

Anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Bugs should be reported(Help->Report a Bug) as there is absolutely nothing that can be done about them here on Blender Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: We don't either, 2.8 is not ready yet, please be patient and wait for the final release

Comment: Hi Duarte.

I'm not being impatient - I realize it's a dev build. I'm just asking if anyone knows any way to make this work. I don't have much experience with Blender yet, and REALLY like the new version.

Actually, I'm surprised it isn't a full version release!

Cheers

Comment: It seems to be a bug. You should look into reporting it. That will include checking if it is not already reported and making sure one can reproduce the issue in the latest builds. If it seems like a bug, chances are - it is. If you wanted to make sure maybe asking about it on forums like Blenderartists.org would be better. There is nothing wrong with the question, it's just that questions about bugs are considered off topic on Blender Stack Exchange. I think it is because answers to them will not be relevant for this community and people finding them online later as they are temporary.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand this as rudeness or refusing to help. I wish I could help, but there is really not much that can be done here. And it is also kind of a rule of the site - see: [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the software. How would I know if it's a bug?

Comment: Hi again Martin (couldn't edit my previous post) Also- I see I need a developer account to report through Blender... ok, I'll do it. I assume once I'm in I'll be able to search known issues to determine if it's been reported yet.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the settings were correct before the import, then it sounds like a bug.
Download & install the latest version of Blender, it may have been reported & fixed.
It could be the external app, see if others share the same problem with that software before reporting it to blender.

Comment: Thanks... ah, there's a newer version than 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

guess I found a solution.Try change the unit scale from its default value 1.000 to 0.001  [image]